# Test::BDD::Cucumber::Harness::Html breaks UTF-8 characters

Tags: perl, utf-8, cucumber, tap

When I try to print a JSON in a test name using the Test::BDD::Cucumber::Harness::Html i get the the character broken and the following error message:

```
Wide character in print at /home/dragos/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.26.3/lib/site_perl/5.26.3/Test2/Formatter/TAP.pm line 125
```

- The command I run is the following:

```
pherkin -oHtml mockserver > mockTest.html
```

- The code that is executed is following:

```
use Test2::V0;

  Then
    qr/test utf8 string/,
    sub {
      my $data =  Mojo::File->new('test.json')->slurp();

      $data = Encode::decode('utf8', $data);
      is(1, 1, $data);
      is $server->get(S->{'url'}),
        'Hello stranger.', 'Welcome screen found';
    };
```

- The JSON body is:

```
{
  "address5": "DUMLUPINAR MAHALLESİ",
}
```

The result looks like this:

```
ok 1 - {
    #        "address5": "DUMLUPINAR MAHALLESÄ°",
    #      }
    #
```

Comment: See also [this](https://github.com/pherkin/test-bdd-cucumber-perl/issues/125) issue

Answer (score 3):

The pherkin ouput utf8 encoded. Capture it with back ticks and decode it the write it to a file.

```
use Encode qw(decode encode encode_utf8);
use autodie;
 

    my $filename = 'test.html';
    # capture  STDOUT and decode the utf8 chars
    # App::pherkin::_pre_run
    # and Test::BDD::Cucumber::Executor::_test_output
    # both open STDOUT in utf8 mode 
    my $output = `pherkin -oHtml mockserver`;
    open( my $fh, '>', $filename );
    print $fh decode('utf8', $output);
```

Comment: This doesn't look right. You opened a filehandle without any layers, so it expects bytes. The output of backticks without any `use open` in scope is already encoded bytes, as such a filehandle would expect. The decoding step would just cause the wide character warning because you are printing characters to a byte stream.

Comment: @Grinnz App::pherkin::_pre_run and Test::BDD::Cucumber::Executor::_test_output both open STDOUT, in  ':utf8' mode. The only this was to decode the output at end or mess in with perkin or Test::BDD::Cucumber::Executor.

Comment: STDOUT is not involved in this answer, just a filehandle you opened.

Comment: this was fixed with the merge of this pr https://github.com/pherkin/test-bdd-cucumber-perl/pull/191